# Running .sh file CentOS6

Tags: linux, centos, shell-script

I have a script for installing a program.

> https://github.com/mkonecny/airtime_centos/blob/master/centos.sh

When I try to run it I get:

```
64-bit installer only
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
install/uninstall parameter required
```

I tried `chmod` it.  I tried `sudo ./centos.sh`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You are in fact successfully running the script.** What you're seeing is the script's output.

```
64 bit installer only
```

from

```
mach=`uname -m`
if [[ "$mach" != "x86_64" ]]; then
    echo "64-bit installer only"
fi
```

This is telling you that the installer script is only meant to be run on x86_64 (64-bit PC) hardware, and your computer is using a different processor architecture (your operating system is probably 32 bit)

At this point, the script should logically quit, but the scripter forgot to put that in, and the script just runs on.

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

This is the output of

```
locale | grep "LANG" | grep -i "UTF.*8"
```

The script uses this to check that your system uses unicode. In my opinion, the scripter is being sloppy here again and should have suppressed the output of that line.

Finally,

```
install/uninstall parameter required
```

is from the last part of the script:

```
if [[ "$1" == "install" ]]; then
    install
elif [[ "$1" == "uninstall" ]]; then
    uninstall
else
    echo "install/uninstall parameter required"
fi
```

The script is trying to tell you that you're supposed to run it like so:

```
./airtime_centos.sh install
```

or, to uninstall,

```
./airtime_centos.sh uninstall
```

However, that probably won't actually work as expected since the script will try to install 64-bit packages on your 32-bit system.

Comment: /centos.sh install
-bash: ./centos.sh: Permission denied

Comment: the thing is it is a unix software that is supported on 32 bit...but no guide was written for centos so a user created this file..this is the original page -> http://en.flossmanuals.net/airtime-en-2-0/manual-installation/

Comment: `-bash: ./centos.sh: Permission denied` is your shell, _bash_, telling you that it does not have the rights to execute the file. You have to set the execute bit using `chmod +x`.

Comment: its working after chmod +x and install after ./centos.sh :) and it seems its defaulting to i686 packages..so well see...thank you all for your kind help!

Answer (score 1):

Try enter in to root
then type

```
 bash   file_path/yourfile.sh
```

...